# How do I read one value from a JSON file using Go

Tags: json, go

I an new to programming in `Go` so apologies if this is something obvious. I have a `JSON` file named `foo.json`:

```
{"type":"fruit","name":"apple","color":"red"}
```

and I am writing a `Go` program that has to do something when the "name" value in the JSON file is "apple". It needs no other information from that JSON file as that file is used for a completely different purpose in another area of the code.

I have read documentation on Decode() and Unmarshal() and abut 30 different web pages describing how to read the whole file into structures, etc. but it all seems extremely complicated for what I want to do which is just write the correct code to implement the first 2 lines of this pseudo-code:

```
file, _ := os.Open("foo.json")
name = file["name"]
if (name == "apple") {
    do stuff
}
```

such that I end up with a `Go` variable named `name` that contains the string value `apple`. What is the right way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method to do what you want is to decode into a struct.

Provided the format remains similar to   `{"type":"fruit","name":"apple","color":"red"}`

```
type Name struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

var data []byte
data, _ = ioutil.ReadFile("foo.json")

var str Name
_ = json.Unmarshal(data, &str)

if str.Name == "apple" {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Your other option is to use third party libraries such as [`gabs`](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) or [`jason`](https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason).

Gabs :

```
jsonParsed, err := gabs.ParseJSON(data)
name, ok := jsonParsed.Path("name").Data().(string)
```

Jason :

```
v, _ := jason.NewObjectFromBytes(data)
name, _ := v.GetString("name")
```

---

Update :

The structure

```
type Name struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

is the json equivalent of `{"name":"foo"}`.

So unmarshaling won't work for the following json with different formats.

```
[{"name":"foo"}]

{"bar":{"name":"foo"}}
```

PS : As mentioned by `W.K.S`. In your case an anonymous struct would suffice since you're not using this structure for anything else.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly declare `data`. Also, if there's only one output (i.e. `err` from `json.Unmarshal()`)and you're deciding to ignore it, then there's no need to assign the output at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say `Provided the format remains similar to..` - what would be an example of it becoming dis-similar and result in breaking the code?

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry, was away for Christmas. Updated.

Comment: @W.K.S I explicitly declared `data` to make is clear that it was a `[]byte`, since it was being used for the other examples as well (gabs & jason). 

And put in the `_ = json.Unmarshal` to make it clear that I was masking the error  since it was sample code. :)

Comment: @JohnSPerayil thanks for the clarification, it makes sense that the Go structure would need to match the JSON structure in terms of nested levels.

Answer (score 4):

One thing is reading a file and other one is decoding a JSON document. I leave you a full example doing both. To run it you have to have a file called `file.json` in the same directory of your code or binary executable:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("file.json") // file.json has the json content
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc := make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bb, &doc); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if name, contains := doc["name"]; contains {
        log.Printf("Happy end we have a name: %q\n", name)
    } else {
        log.Println("Json document doesn't have a name field.")
    }

    log.Printf("full json: %s", string(bb))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0u04MwwGfn

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to find out a little more about the 3 different approaches suggested here (to decode into an Interface (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41294843/1745001 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41295594/1745001), or a Named structure (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41296043/1745001), or an Unnamed structure (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41296207/1745001). ) and then I'll start testing.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in the end I went with the named structure approach as that is apparently the convention in some other code for the product I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

The proper Go way of doing this would be to decode into an instance of an anonymous struct containing only the field you need.

```
func main() {
    myStruct := struct{ Name string }{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"type":"fruit","name":"apple","color":"red"}`), &myStruct)
    fmt.Print(myStruct.Name)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/R4THsaW1q3)

Alternatively, You could use [Jeffails/gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) JSON Parser:

```
jsonParsed,_ := gabs.ParseJSON([]byte(`{"type":"fruit","name":"apple","color":"red"}`));
value, ok = jsonParsed.Path("name").Data().(string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I seem to have 3 choices to decode into - an Interface (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41294843/1745001 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41295594/1745001), a Named structure (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41296043/1745001), or an Unnamed structure (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41296207/1745001). Are there any pros/cons to either approach beyond possible code brevity?

Comment: I'd say it depends on what your requirements are. Decoding into an interface makes sense when, say, a web api returns a different json structure depending on the request parameters it receives. When the json structure is known, a struct makes more sense: A named struct would be preferable when the json structure maps directly to an entity in your application. On the other hand, when the json does not represent an entity and you simply need to read the value of a few field (such as in your question), an anonymous struct would suffice.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. It does sound like an unnamed struct would be the way to do this for my case (reading a config file that rarely changes). Now to testing...

Comment: In your question, you mentioned that this configuration file rarely changes and is not that relevant to your application. In this context, I agree, you're best of using an anonymous struct. However, In general, I do prefer to define a Configuration struct because it clearly documents what the configuration fields are and their data types. Additionally you can use enumerators for readability and associate convenience functions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in the end I went with the named structure approach as that is apparently the convention in some other code for the product I'm working on.

Comment: This works quite well if the value you're trying to retrieve is not too deep in the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to find a simple solution such as `$d = json_decode($json, true)` in PHP and came to the conclusion that there is no such simple way in Golang. The following is the simplest solution I could make *(the checks are skipped for clarity)*:

```
var f interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(file, &f)

m := f.(map[string]interface{})
if (m["name"] == "apple") {
  // Do something
}
```

where

- `file` is an array of bytes of JSON string,
- `f` interface serves as a generic container for unknown JSON structure,
- `m` is a map returned by the [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

We can assert that `f` is a map of strings, because `Unmarshal()` builds a variable of that type for any JSON input. At least, I couldn't make it return something different. It is possible to detect the type of a variable by means of [run-time reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/):

```
fmt.Printf("Type of f = %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(f))
```

For the `f` variable above, the code will print `Type of f = map[string]interface {}`.

## Example

And this is the full code with necessary checks:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "io/ioutil"
  "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
  // Read entire file into an array of bytes
  file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("foo.json")
  if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed read file: %s\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  var f interface{}
  err = json.Unmarshal(file, &f)
  if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to parse JSON: %s\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  // Type-cast `f` to a map by means of type assertion.
  m := f.(map[string]interface{})
  fmt.Printf("Parsed data: %v\n", m)

  // Now we can check if the parsed data contains 'name' key
  if (m["name"] == "apple") {
    fmt.Print("Apple found\n")
  }
}
```

*Output*

```
Parsed data: map[type:fruit name:apple color:red]
Apple found
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in the end I went with the named structure approach as that is apparently the convention in some other code for the product I'm working on.